# how to wordpress loop for each with database query

Tags: wordpress

So I'm trying to custom code a loop using for_each in WordPress so that it displays a code (city) for each table that has a state name.. my outcome would be like this displayed;

```
- New York
  -- city1
  -- city2
  -- city3
- New Jersey
  -- city1
  -- city2
```

and so on.. in the database (mysql) each entry is placed into a row with table for State and Table for City but in same row...

I've tried doing the following but I'm failing in it;

```
$states = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_em_locations WHERE location_state=*);
$city = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_em_locations WHERE location_town=*);
foreach ( $states as $state ) {
echo '$state';
echo '$city';
}
```

Comment: Use **correct** handling for variables! `echo '$state';` wont work! Use `echo $state;` **or** `echo "$state";`

Comment: I believe your syntax is incorrect.  Shouldn't you be obtaining the $city information based on the $state that you obtain?  Inside the foreach $state you should obtain the $wpdb info based on the state you are listing and have its own foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:  get_row may not be the best method of gaining this infomration.  I am using your context to get this information but this may be the method you are looking for.

```
$states = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT location_state FROM wp_em_locations GROUP BY location_state");
foreach ( $states as $state ) {
  echo $state->location_state;
  $cities = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT location_town FROM wp_em_locations WHERE location_state = '" . $state . "'");
  foreach ($cities as $city) {
      echo $city->location_town;
  }
}
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

Comment: yes looks like a better write up, however I'm not getting anything tho.

Comment: Updated my answer.  I saw my mistake.

Comment: @Robert_Lee not sure but still blanks... am I forgetting the closing arguments or something. I am putting this in between `<?php` and `?>` right? sorry, I'm just bad when it gets to database stuff.

Comment: just to make clear the table is wp_em_locations and the column is location_state, database name is named 'events'

Comment: For you to pull information from a different database than your Wordpress database you would not be able to use $wpdb to get your results.  If this table was inside the same database as your Wordpress installation this would work.

Comment: ok, no its in the same database. Not sure why I'm getting blanks/nothing. If I run this in my DB `SELECT location_state FROM $wpdb->wp_em_locations GROUP BY location_state` I get results

Comment: I updated the Cities result to see if that makes a difference. Just to debug.  If you remove the lines getting the cities do you at least get the states listed?

Comment: yes, I get the states but without `$wpdb->` in there.. so for states `$states = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT location_state FROM wp_em_locations GROUP BY location_state");` works..

Comment: Here updated answer..  try the same thing for cities.